# Doctrine behavior with cascade={"remove"} on a OneToMany relation with a ManyToOne to same entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

i have two entities : Post and Comments where a Post can have one or more comments.

I implemented a cascade={"remove"} on the Post's comments OneToMany which works greats ! 
All comments related to a Posts gets deleted after Post suppression.
Then, i decided to add a **topComment** attribute in my Post Entity (Many topComment to One Post). After that, i tried to delete a Post with related Comments but the suppression fails because of the foreign key constraint even if the post have no topComment...
Here is the error i get :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lab_test_cascade_remove`.`comment`, CONSTRAINT `FK_9474526C4B89032C` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`id`))
```

I got rid of this error by adding a `@JoinColumn(nullable=true)` annotation to the Post's topComment attribute but i find that strange because this is the default behavior of doctrine if @JoinColumn annotation isn't set...

Could someone can please explain me what happens internally and cause this error even if the Post don't have any topComment ?

Many thanks in advance.

Here are my entities (attributes only) :

**Post** :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="post", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private $comments;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment")
     */
    private $topComment;
```

**Comment :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CommentRepository")
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $post;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
```

Comment: Please have a read of [Association Updates: Owning Side and Inverse Side](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork-associations.html) docs. What you have done with this is created the situation that a Post and a Comment are both the "owning" side. To create a "TopComment", create it as a separate Entity, which references both a Comment (single) and a Post (single).

Comment: @rkeet has right. You have loop now: Post->Comments->Posts->...

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i read the doc and understand what you said as the concept of loop i created which is wrong. Do you know why i don't get the error anymore by adding @JoinColumn(nullable=true) annotation to the Post's topComment attribute ?

Comment: Why do you not add just a is_top_comment attribute to comment entity. If it is true, the comment is top else it is not top.